# ParseServer PFFile distorted link

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mlab, parse-server

I migrated my Parse data from Parse.com to MongoDB + Heroku. I'm able to successfully fetch data from the new database. However, One of the objects has a PFFile. When I try to extract it's url, I get something like this:

```
https:/files.parsetfss.com/044cdf35-4d09-40e2-aa06-2472e2317669/tfss-29248a63-3239-46f1-8e82-9380e3f3a1e1-file -- file:///
```

However, it's supposed to look like this:

```
https://files.parsetfss.com/044cdf35-4d09-40e2-aa06-2472e2317669/tfss-29248a63-3239-46f1-8e82-9380e3f3a1e1-file
```

It's adding something at the end of the link and the https has only one slash. If the "-- file:///" is removed and you try the link, it will download the image. Else, it will show up some weird text as AccessDenied.

So far, I placed my fileKey in the index.js file and uploaded to Heroku. What could be missing here? anyone encountered the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this as well. If I revert to the previous Parse config prior to migrating, everything works like a charm. Once I update the config to the new parse server, I get this issue. It only appears to be specific to PFFiles too.

Comment: this is useful as a comment but cannot be considered as a full answer to the question